# Creating a matrix with runtime dimentions as input

Tags: c, matrix, runtime

There are two cods that I have written. One works while the other wont. Please explain the working of this code wand why the latter isnt working.

Working -

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main(){
  int m, n, i, j;
  scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
  int *p;
  p = (int *) malloc(m*n*sizeof(int));
  for(i=0;i<m;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
      scanf("%d", (p+i*n+j));
    }
  }
}
```

Not Working -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main(){
  int m, n, i, j;
  scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
  int *p;
  p = (int *) malloc(m*n*sizeof(int));
  for(i=0;i<m;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
      scanf("%d", p[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

> error is - subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
>   scanf("%d", p[i][j]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second example then `p` would need to be a pointer to an array, or a pointer to pointer.

It could be something like

```
int **p = malloc(m * sizeof(int *));
for (size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i)
{
    p[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        scanf("%d", &p[i][j]);
    }
}
```